# Facebook pages - best practice flow

Tags: facebook, authentication

What is the best way to allow a user to post something to their apps page.

Note I'm not talking about pages the app owns, but pages the users of the app own.

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

manage_pages and publish_stream are required